# How to tell if a business is open after midnight

Tags: swift

I've looked at this question, but a lot of it doesn't make sense nor work:
[How to determine if a business is open given the hours of operation (Swift-iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37486365/how-to-determine-if-a-business-is-open-given-the-hours-of-operation-swift-ios)

Some places on my list open at like 7:30 am and close the next day at 4 am. I have the times on my Parse-server listed as such:
openTime (Number): 7.5 (for 7:30 am) 
closeTime (Number): and 4 for (4 am)

However, when I use the logic from the linked questions,

```
if now.hour! > Int(openTime) && now.hour! < Int(closeTime) {}
```

it keeps saying that business is closed. How could I adjust the numbers or the logic, in order to make it work for places that close late night / early morning the next day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider that `closeTime` must be superior to `openTime`, otherwise its the day after.

so it will become something like:

```
let realCloseTime = closeTime < openTime ? closeTime + 24 : closeTime
if now.hour! > Int(openTime) && now.hour! < Int(realCloseTime) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have a problem with minutes. Stores that open at 7:30 will report being open at 7:00. Stores that close at 11:30 will report being closed at 11:00.

Assuming that open and close are doubles.

```
var openTime: Double
var closeTime: Double
```

then

```
func isOpen(at date: Date = Date()) -> Bool {
    guard let openDate = createDate(bySettingHours: openTime, of: date) else { return false }
    guard let closeDate = createDate(bySettingHours: closeTime, of: date) else { return false }
    guard let adjustedCloseDate = add24Hours(to: closeDate) else { return false }

    let realCloseDate = openDate < closeDate ? closeDate : adjustedCloseDate

    return openDate <= date && date <= realCloseDate
}

private func createDate(bySettingHours double: Double, of date: Date) -> Date? {
    let hour = Int(floor(double)) % 24
    let minute = Int(double * 30) % 30

    return Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: hour, minute: minute, second: 0, of: date)
}

private func add24Hours(to date: Date) -> Date? {
    return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 24, to: date)
}
```

---

I was assuming you have some kind of model like

```
class Business {
    var openTime: Double
    var closeTime: Double
}
```

My suggestion was to add the `isOpen(at:)` method here.

```
class Business {
    var openTime: Double
    var closeTime: Double

    func isOpen(at date: Date = Date()) -> Bool {
        // implmentation
    } 
}
```

It would be used something like this

```
var business = Business()

// Setup `business`

business.isOpen()

// or

let now = Date()
business.isOpen(at: now)
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I am confused as to how to use the isOpen function you created; how do I return the boolean when isOpen is true or false?